# Using fadeIn and fadeOut in jQuery at the same time as transition in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using fadeIn and fadeOut to animate an object into and out of view. I want to also animate the "left"-property of the object at the same time. This works for fadeOut in my example, but not fadeIn. In my original work it works on fadeIn, but on fadeOut the transition comes before the fade.

That is, the object first moves to its new location, and then fades out.

What needs to be done to get a CSS transition to happen at the same time as a jQuery fade?

```js
$('.wrapper').click(function() {
  var thisInClick = this;
  if ($(thisInClick).hasClass('show')) {
    $(thisInClick).toggleClass('show');
    $(thisInClick).find('.box').fadeOut(1000);
   } else {
    $(thisInClick).toggleClass('show');
    $(thisInClick).find('.box').fadeIn(1000);
   }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 70%;
 display: none;
  transition: left 0.5s ease-out;
}

.wrapper.show .box {
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "box">
    I AM BOX
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uev2qzso/1/

EDIT: I should have mentioned that the original code used opacity transition in CSS. The problem is that what I am showing are two links, and if you click over them while they have opacity:0; they will fire. I need to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the css a bit to get all the animation on screen.
If I understand correctly, you can use JQuery function events callback. In this case the `start` event.

```js
$('.wrapper').click(function() {
  var thisInClick = this;
  if ($(thisInClick).hasClass('show')) {
    $(thisInClick).find('.box').fadeOut({
        duration: 1000,
        start: function() {
          $(thisInClick).toggleClass('show');
         }
        });
   } else {
    
    $(thisInClick).find('.box').fadeIn({
        duration: 1000,
        start: function() {
          $(thisInClick).toggleClass('show');
         }
        });
   }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 70%;
 display: none;
  transition: left 0.5s ease-out;
}

.wrapper.show .box {
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "box">
    I AM BOX
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because it pertains better to the question than the other answers. I chose to go with pointer-events: none; in CSS for a more clean and minimal way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your Edit line. You can use the CSS property `pointer-events: none` when the elements have `opacity: 0` and then `pointer-events: all` when the element are `opacity:1` to avoid the links getting clicked or fired. Hope this helps!

Comment: Though this does not answer the question directly, it solves my initial problem in the cleanest way. I went with this one.

Comment: yes, it's maybe the cleanest and easiest way. Can you please upvote if this was of a help for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code **`.fadeToggle()`**.  It will help you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution, move the fade to the CSS

https://jsfiddle.net/ud6s5yxt/1/

```
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 70%;
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.wrapper.show .box {
  left: 10%;
  opacity:1;
}


$('.wrapper').click(function() {
        var thisInClick = this;
        $(thisInClick).toggleClass('show');
});



<div class = "wrapper">
  <div class = "box">
    I AM BOX
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned in the question that this was the original code. The problem is that what I am showing are two links, and if you click over them while they have opacity:0; they will fire. I need to avoid this.